# How do I edit a trigger in PSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

To edit a function I type:

```
\ef function_name()
```

But I can't find any documentation on editing a trigger?

I've tried the same syntax but it just says my trigger function does not exist.

Comment: Do you want to edit the trigger function or the trigger definition?

Comment: trigger definition